# Delete images that can't be found

Tags: python, add-on

I'm writing an add on, and in it I attempt to pack all the textures for a given model. However, sometimes my script fails because it can't find the source.

I'm wondering if there is a way in python to delete all the images that "bpy.ops.file.report_missing_files()" returns?

Answer (score 3):

It isn't hard to make a list of missing images, removing them from `bpy.data.images` isn't always easy. The image knows how many times it is used but not where it is used, you will need to look through textures and nodes to find where it is used to clear the users before you will be allowed to delete the image.

I would suggest testing the existence of the image before packing rather than trying to cleanup the blend file. Use [`bpy.path.abspath()`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.path.html#bpy.path.abspath) to get the true filepath for the image (this turns '//' into a real filepath) and then use [`os.path.exists()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) to check if there is a file you can pack.

```
import bpy, os

for i in bpy.data.images:
    if i.filepath:
        ipath = bpy.path.abspath(i.filepath)
        if os.path.exists(ipath):
            i.pack()
```

As you come across a missing image you could add it to a list and report the missing files when you are done. Maybe create the list in the text editor for the user to look through.